# Restrict Related Products by Product Categories Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have done a fair bit of searching on this but to no avail.

My question is that i wish to narrow the term by which woocommerce defines a related product. It currently uses Categories & Tags to define related products, but i wish to remove tags and just link by product categories. The result of this would be only products in my store with the same category would be defined as a related product. Note i am not using subcategories.

Can someone help me out with the code i would need to use to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In the  `abstract-wc-product.php` file in the `woocommerce/includes/abstracts/` folder remove the following line (on line ~1154):

```
// Get tags
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $this->id, 'product_tag' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $tags_array[] = $term->term_id;
}
```

Removing the above should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this does not appear to work. It mostly removes related products altogether, although in rare instances it will display related products with the same category (which is correct), but there must be something further conflicting.

Comment: Not a good idea to edit core files, it breaks the update path. Use hooks or filters to edit the functionality, where available.